# Convertir y cambiar valores TRUE Y FALSE

Tags: php, json

Hola amigos espero me puedan ayudar porque la realidad es que no doy, les explico:
Tego un JSON que me regresa en la respuesta varios valores en "is_locked_on_sim_swap" donde me devielve un TRUE o FALSE segun sea el caso, necesito cambiar esos valores Bloqueado o Desbloqueado, sin embargo ya consegui cambiar TRUE a Bloqueado pero no consigo que cuando la respuesta sea FALSE me devuelva Desbloqueado, les adjunto el codigo hasta donde logre que todo funcionara, pero despues de esa parte ya no supe que hacer.

```
<?php 

$cadena = json_encode($device_info['is_locked_on_sim_swap']);
$resultado = str_replace('true', 'Bloqueado', $cadena); 
echo $resultado; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)** admite también en parámetro conjuntos de argumentos. Por tanto, si quieres buscar/reemplazar más de un elemento, puedes pasar dos arrays, uno con las cadenas a buscar y otro con las cadenas a reemplazar.

Por ejemplo:

```
$cadena="Esto es true y esto es false";
$cadena=str_replace(
    array("true","false"),
    array("Bloqueado","Desbloqueado"),
    $cadena
); 
echo $cadena;
```

**Salida:**

```
Esto es Bloqueado y esto es Desbloqueado
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono a la perfeccion

Answer (score 0):

con eso:

```
$cadena = json_encode($device_info['is_locked_on_sim_swap']);
$cadena = str_replace(['true','false'],['Bloqueado','Desbloqueado'],$cadena);
echo $cadena; ?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono a la perfeccion